# Regenarate location if (X,Y) already contains ImageView there

Tags: android

I have an `ImageViewArray` and I am randomizing their locations, I want to check if the current location already contains an `ImageView` without keeping a lot of values of `x,y` for every `ImageView` in the array. 
Here is my code:

```
   ImageView[] imageViewArray = new ImageView[40];
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(this);
        imageViewArray[i].setTag(i);
        imageViewArray[i].setImageResource(R.mipmap.enemy);
        rlt.addView(imageViewArray[i]);
        imageViewArray[i].setX(rand.nextInt(rlt.getWidth()));
        imageViewArray[i].setY(rand.nextInt(rlt.getHeight()));
        if(imageViewArray[i].getX()=) // here I want to check if it already contains an ImageView.
    }
```

**Possible Solution**

Creating IntArray and adding X value to it and also every Y value for it, then compare between them, is it the best solution?

Problem with the solution - nothing happens, the imageview doesn't change the place and the Toast is not executed.

code:

```
        ImageView[] imageViewArray = new ImageView[20];
    ArrayList<Float> xarray = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> yarray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(this);
        imageViewArray[i].setTag(i);
        imageViewArray[i].setImageResource(R.mipmap.enemy);
        imageViewArray[i].setX((float)rand.nextInt(1 + layoutwidth));
        imageViewArray[i].setY((float)rand.nextInt(1 + layoutheight));
        xarray.add(imageViewArray[i].getX());
        yarray.add(imageViewArray[i].getY());
        rlt.addView(imageViewArray[i]);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,imageViewArray[i].getX() +"blabla",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
```

**EDIT**

layoutwidth is zero :

```
private int layoutwidth, layoutheight, randx, randy;
private RelativeLayout rlt;
.... 
        rlt = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    rlt.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            rlt.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            layoutwidth = rlt.getWidth();
            layoutheight = rlt.getHeight();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the best solution. You need to load the rectangles from somewhere. You might merge rectangles if one contains the other, but then you would over-complicate your task and in your quest of writing a more performant and a clearer code, you would end up with a slow and complicated code. Write your code with storing pairs of X, Y points where X is the let-top corner position and Y is the right-bottom corner position.

Note, that I have assumed that the pictures are not rotated. If the images might be rotated, then you need a more general solution, using the inequalities defining the rectangles to see where a point set of a rectangle intersects the point set of the other rectangle. If the intersection is empty set, then the "space is not used up".

Comment: The images are not rotated, it's images of 2 creatures that move etc.. and you need to avoid them.. that's all, I will use the intarray, thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please check the code added? it is not working, the imageView doesn't change it position. they stay at the same place, any idea why?

Comment: I believe you should debug the code. Add a breakpoint into that method and see when the code gets there (if it gets there) whether everything is executed as expected. If you experience some anomalies, then they are potential causes of the problem.

Comment: layoutwidth is a variable. Maybe it was not initialized for a reason. Can you show me how did you initialize it?

Comment: Can you debug the code? What is the value of rlt.getWidth() when you initialize layoutwidth?

Comment: it is zero, in the method I added a toast message to show rlt.getWidth() and it said 0...

Comment: That's the problem. The view is not initialized properly (yet) and the width is 0. .nextInt(1 + layoutwidth) is .nextInt(1) which will result in 0.

Comment: Yes, I need to get width in a different way.

Comment: In general, it is not a bad idea to create a file containing initializing values, like width and before everything else, you read that file storing the settings somewhere, like static members of a Settings class. Later you can read the values from there.